# Script that monitors log file quits unexpectedly

Tags: bash, shell

I've written simple script that monitors elasticsearch.log looking for specific pattern and finally sending curl POST request.

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -F -n 0 elasticsearch.log | \
while read -r line 
do 
  echo "$line" | grep '<PATTERN>'
  if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]] 
  then
    curl -X POST <URL>
  fi
done
```

The problem is that script is quits unexpectedly with 0 exit status. Do you have any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: Add `set -vx` to the top of the script and see what happens right before it exits. Also why bother with `read` there? Why not just pipe straight to `grep` and `read` the output so each line is a matching line already?

Comment: I tried to follow you sugestion: `tail -F -n 0 elasticsearch.log | grep 'pattern' | while read -r line; do curl -X POST <URL>; done` but it doesn't work. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Bash's exit status is that of the last command executed, which in this case is the `while` command.  In turn, its exit status is that of the last command executed in its `do` list.  Thus, neither the exit status of the `read` command nor that of the `tail` command factors into your script's exit status, which makes it somewhat uninformative.  Probably `tail` is exiting for some reason, but I'm uncertain what that reason would be, given that you are using the `-F` option.